# Is this json request for this POST method in this python code are correct?

Tags: python, mysql, json, post, flask

Program is running but I've got problem with post, I've got error 500 and In console I've got

`File "main.py", line 34, in add_user
    cursor.close()
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cursor' referenced before assignment
127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2019 12:03:38] "POST /add HTTP/1.1" 500 -`

```
import pymysql
from app import app
from db_config import mysql
from flask import jsonify
from flask import flash, request


@app.route('/add', methods=['POST'])
def add_user():
    try:
        _json = request.json
        _wartosc = _json['wartosc_pojazdu']
        _email = _json['email']
        _datazakupu = _json['data_zakupu_pojazdu']
        _datarejestracji = _json('data_pierwszejrejestracji')

        if _wartosc and _email and _datazakupu and _datarejestracji and request.method == 'POST':

            # save edits
            sql = "INSERT INTO tbl_gap(id, wartosc, email, data_zakupu_pojazdu, data_pierwszejrejestracji) VALUES(%d, %d, %s, %s, %s)"
            data = (_id, _wartosc, _email, _datazakupu, _datarejestracji)
            conn = mysql.connect()
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(sql, data)
            conn.commit()
            resp = jsonify('User added successfull!')
            resp.status_code = 200
            return resp
        else:
            return not_found()
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        cursor.close() 
        conn.close()

@app.errorhandler(404)
def not_found(error=None):
    message = {
        'status': 404,
        'message': 'Not Found: ' + request.url,
    }
    resp = jsonify(message)
    resp.status_code = 404

    return resp


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()

app= Flask(__name__)
app.config['TESTING'] = True
```

I think the main problem is with json request but I can't find out where.

```
    "wartosc_pojazdu":300,
    "email":"casdf@roytuts.com",
    "data_zakupu_pojazdu":"1992/12/12",
    "data_pierwszejrejestracji": "1992/23/23"
```

is the post request correct ?

Can't find solution for this problem for so long so thank you for any advice.

---

Ok, that helped but I still get information that I've got bad return statement.

```
"The view function did not return a valid response. The" TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement. 127.0.0.1 - - [06/Nov/2019 12:43:32] "POST /add HTTP/1.1" 500 -
```

Answer (score 1):

That's exactly why `try` blocks should be small as possible.

Take a close look at your code. In case the `if` condition is `False`, then `cursor` is not defined. Then, in the `finally` block, you are calling `cursor.close()`, but you can't do it since `cursor` is not defined!

Same goes for `conn`.

The best solution is to make sure the `try` block is as small as possible, maybe move it to inside the `if` condition.

Answer (score 1):

You need to have defined `cursor` in all cases:

```
def add_user():
    try:
        cursor = None
        # other code elided

    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
    finally:
        if cursor:
            cursor.close()
```